# How to type -- or >> in minted?

Tags: minted, code, ligatures

If I try to type `--` or `>>` (resp. `<<`), LaTeX puts them together and makes one big `-`, respectively guillemets. How can I change that behavior? I have to use LuaLaTeX to compile my source.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{shell-session}
$ cat <<EOM >> ./test.txt
> Text
> Text
> EOM
$ application --file ./test.txt
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you please add a full (but short) example, from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`, that shows the problem?

Comment: please provide a complete example including font configuration and tell us if you use pdflatex or lualatex. I can not reproduce issue with up-to-date latex.

Comment: ii edited my questions and added hopefully all informations you need.

Comment: @egreg: hm perhaps disabling `minted`'s cache with `cache=false`...

Comment: if you are using luatex why `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` so disabling most of luatex's font handling?

Comment: @egreg I'm writing on Overleaf, I've made a there a complete example on https://www.overleaf.com/read/csdbvyztsjdn

Comment: @Carlisle we need some Lua-scripts in our document, therefore we need LuaLaTex

Comment: David's question was not why you are using lualatex, but why you are using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and so breaking the font setup of lualatex.

Comment: @cortesis I hadn't seen the mention of LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is best if you don't load `fontenc` with LuaLaTeX. If you really need to, then you can disable ligatures for the monospaced font.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures{encoding = T1, family = tt* }

\begin{document}

This has ligatures: fi fl ffi ffl,
en-dash --,
em-dash ---,
guillemets <<>>


\begin{minted}{shell-session}
$ cat <<EOM >> ./test.txt
> Text
> Text
> EOM
$ application --file ./test.txt
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]